# HTML・JavaScriptを自動解釈してくれるライブラリやツールを探しています。

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, http, c++-cli

■概要
HTML・JavaScriptを自動解釈してくれるライブラリやツールを探しています。

■詳細
疑似WEBブラウザを開発中です。

指定したURLへのHTTPリクエストを飛ばして返ってきたレスポンス(HTML・JavaScript)を自動処理して、
後続のHTTPリクエストも飛ばす、というものです。

1回目のクリエストを飛ばしてレスポンスを取得するところまでは開発が完了していますが、
そのレスポンスを自動で解釈して次のHTTPリクエストを発行する機能を作りたいのです。

これを愚直に行うと、
レスポンス内容の中からURLに該当する文字列をピックアップしてURLを抽出して後続のリクエストを飛ばす・・となってしまいますが、
近年JavaScriptが自動的にリクエストを飛ばす処理も多くみられますので、現実的ではありません。

なので、2回目以降のリクエストを自動的に行うために、
**HTML・JavaScriptを自動解釈して、2回目以降のリクエストURLを抽出してくれる**ようなライブラリやツールを探しています。

良いライブラリやツールをご教授下さい。(URLやライブラリ名など)
厳密じゃなくても似たようなものでも結構です。
※ちなみにWEBブラウザのような表示機能は不要です。あくまでHTTPリクエストを飛ばしたいだけです。

■開発環境(本質問とはあまり関係ないですが一応掲載します)
Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop
C++ CLI(NET Framework)

Comment: JavaScriptによるHTTPリクエストの場合、条件によって実行されたりされなかったりしますが、それも加味するのでしょうか？　その条件は、ユーザ操作であったり、ブラウザのウィンドウサイズであったりするかもしれません。

Comment: マルチポスト先が多いようなので、回答に注意が必要という意味で注意喚起しておきます。
https://teratail.com/questions/86040